# Dataframe : how to create a dynamic reference

Tags: python, dataframe

This is my dataframe:

[DF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmijK.png)

In the last column (D), I would have the value of column C2 if the value of the column B is 2;  C3 value if B=3… for each row.

I tried unsuccessfully.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you post your example dataframe as code? That'll help us help you

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a dictionary for this:

```
vals = [0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4];
convDict = {i+1:val for i,val in enumerate(vals)} # +1 because you used 1 as the base
df['D'] = df['B'].map(convDict)
```

If you really have the dataframe as you've shown in the picture you provided, where all the column entries of c1 to c4 are equal, you can replace vals with:

```
vals = df.loc[0,'C1':'C4'].values
```

If the values in c1 through c4 are unequal, I would take the following approach:

```
A = df.loc[:,['C1':'C4']].values
y = df['B'].values.astype(int)-1
x = np.arange(len(y)).astype(int)
df['D'] = A[x,y]
```

Comment: Interesting but what if the C1-C4 values are not the same on each rows ?

Comment: Thank’s.
To expand, my dataframe contains 600 000 rows and the values are not the same as it has shown in this simplified dataframe , but an identical architecture.

Comment: ok, will provide an example of unequal entries in the columns c1 through c4

Answer (score 0):

The C1-C4 values are not the same.

My detailed dataframe : df

```
anc    PM0       LR1     LR2    ....   LR41          R1               R2    R3 ... R40
 2     1500      0.05    0.02          0.05   "LR"&'anc'=LR2 => 0.02  LR3   LR4   LR41
 3     2500      0.02    0.03          0.012      LR3 value           LR4   LR5   LR42
 4     150.23    0.03    0.036         0.05       LR4 value 
 12    220       0.05    0.09          0.03       LR12 value   
 11    3330      0.06    0.01          0.02       LR11 value
```

....

-> 600 000 Rows

i would to create 41 columns R1-R41, function of the 'anc' column value.

If 'anc'=2  then,  R1=LR2.value   R2=LR3.value ...    R41=LR42.value

and this for each 600 000 rows

I tried this following code

for i in range(1,41)
df['R'+str(i)] = df["LR"+(df['anc']+i).astype(str)]

but I get a 'memory error'

Thanks a lot.